# Should custom close-voting comments be flagged as obsolete if the question is reopened?

Tags: discussion, comments, reopen-closed, comment-flags, obsolete-information

The question [What's the purpose of “This page is intentionally left blank” we see in books?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/81825/52226) was initially closed as off-topic, and there was a comment explaining why. This comment got many upvotes.

The question was later reopened, but the comment suggesting off-topicness has not been removed.

**Question**: Should I flag those comments as obsoleted (and delete them if I can)?

[image]

Comment: @NathanTuggy thanks for your edit in title. I didn't recognize that I hadn't finished my title yet. I wonder what you mean *custom* when you add it? I have checked the dictionary and I suspect the closest definition of it is *habitual* or *traditional*. Am I correct?

Comment: I mean "customized"; that's what the free-form text reasons are usually called.

Comment: @NathanTuggy is it universal or just a common saying in SE?

Comment: Using "custom" in that sense is conventional English; SE is in the habit of using that, but it's not unique jargon, just settling on a particular common way of saying things as the technical term to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really I think. This reflects the opinion of a large group of users and is relevant still at this time. It is always possible for a user that didn't vote to close yet to reuse this close reason.

Also it says 'Hey, this question was closed because of this and some people found the question useful so voted to reopen. Keep it that way!'.

Either way: it is useful information.

If it stays open for some time, it could indeed be considered obsolete. Since the question is quite new, I would keep it some longer.

Comment: I find this a little bit confusing advice, specially if the question already went through a close/reopen cycle. I would rather get rid of such comments to not trigger 'follow-up' close votes and/or extra attention. if there is a close/reopen war going on it is early enough to leave a comment to make users aware of that and clean-up any comment that led to that war.

Comment: Do you agree with this answer I ask on Health? [Should I flag mod comments about lacking of reference if they are obsoleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/381/99)