# Having a meta of each question?

Tags: discussion, comments, questions, meta, content

I'm not saying the meta of the site, I'm talking about the meta of each question. You can think it like the history section, or the same as the edit page in every Wikipedia page, or the revisions page with the ability to comment. I'd like to choose the name "meta of the question" to harmonize with the meta we already know.

Here and there, you will see the comments say: I'm VTC this, because XYZ. With the site as it is now, the only way to say so is the comment section. But the comments are not for discussing about the fate of the question, but to **attribute to the content**. If for some reasons, the question doesn't get closed, then that comment will be obsolete, and should be moved away from other good *content* comments. But since it is a voice, an opinion, it should be recorded in the back of the question, e.g. its meta.

Doing this, we will have two advantages:

- Remove the fluff from the content, while keeping the voice to be heard*.
- Decrease the burden to ask trivial questions in the meta site. Some meta questions can be answered quick and easy**, it shouldn't need a whole community to look at it. Let those energy to spend on the important things. If the meta of the question is serious enough, it can be convert to the question of the meta.

What do you think?

<sub>*[Should custom close-voting comments be flagged as obsolete if the question is reopened?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/262311/260800)

**Like this one: [A question which closely related to a lot of other questions that is not closed as dupe?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2008/14341)</sub>

Comment: But we have [specific-question] on any meta already.

Comment: oh, I didn't aware of it. Anyway, my two bullets still valid

Comment: But I imagine people would visit this question meta way less.

Answer (score 3):

In three words: not worth (the) efforts. (development efforts, that is)

Comments *can* be used for those things, even if they're not the ideal mechanism. Closing a question should not happen in the first place in a proper question, so having it closed means something is wrong. In those cases, "misusing" the comments is not such a bad idea - after all, trying to justify the closure, or to prevent the closure, might affect the fate of the question.

Comment: I would say that any effort to develop will be worth in the long run (there is a xkcd for that, but I can't google out). But as in the first link, not always having it closed means it is bad

Comment: @Ooker yeah, but not when the new mechanism is already "covered" in some existing mechanism.

Comment: which part it doesn't cover?

Comment: What I mean is that what you suggest is already possible via comments. Not 100% elegant, right, but totally possible

Comment: @Ooker if you want to give up on this just let me know and I have no problem removing the answer, then you'll be able to delete.

Comment: I just come back. Yeah I think I should give up, but why removing the answer? It's helpful right?

Comment: @Ooker sort of, but on the other hand I do believe it is your right to "regret" suggesting this feature.